# GCC & binutils build - C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c++, c, gcc, build, binutils

I'm trying to build gcc-5.3 and binutils-2.26.  I've done it like this:

```bash
mkdir gcc; cd gcc
wget http://path/to/gcc-5.3.0.tar.bz2
wget http://path/to/binutils-2.26.tar.bz2
tar xf gcc-5.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xf binutils-2.26.tar.bz2
cd gcc-5.3.0
contrib/download_prerequisites
for file in ../binutils-2.26/*; do ln -s "${file}"; done
cd ..
mkdir build
mkdir dist
cd build
../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/teamcity/gcc/dist --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --program-suffix=-mine
make
```

This appears to build the first stage executables okay; `prev-gas`, `prev-gcc`, `prev-ld` are all present with plausible-looking executables in them.  But the next stage fails:

```
Configuring stage 2 in ./intl
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc...  /home/teamcity/gcc/build/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/home/teamcity/gcc/build/./prev-gcc/ -B/home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include -L/home/teamcity/gcc/build/./ld
checking for C compiler default output file name...
configure: error: in `/home/teamcity/gcc/build/intl':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The relevant bit of config.log appears to be this:

```
configure:2978: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3000:  /home/teamcity/gcc/build/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/home/teamcity/gcc/build/./prev-gcc/ -B/home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unkn
own-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/teamcity/gcc/dist/x86_64-unknown-l
inux-gnu/sys-include -L/home/teamcity/gcc/build/./ld    -g -O2 -gtoggle  -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  conftest.c  >&5
/home/teamcity/gcc/build/./prev-gcc/as: 106: exec: /home/teamcity/gcc/build/./gas/as-new: not found
```

This looks like prev-gcc's as is expecting to find `gas/as-new`, when actually it's `prev-gas/as-new`.

Is there some workaround for this?  Is it safe to just `ln -s prev-gas gas`?  I'd sort of expect that to cause problems later on.  Is it not possible to build these two versions of gcc and binutils together?

Comment: Typo:
wget http://path/to/binutils-5.3.0.tar.bz2 should probably have 2.26 rather than 5.3.0 in the path?

Comment: Quite right.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Should have also mentioned the build platform is Ubuntu 14.04, using GCC 4.8 installed with the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my edited answer after trying it on my own on an Ubuntu 14.04 Azure VM.

The following approach worked for me:

- Build and install binutils 2.26; for the purposes of this discussion,
  let's say it's installed in /opt/gcc-5.3.0.
- Configure gcc-5.3.0 in a build directory using `/root/objdir/../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-5.3.0
  --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --with-ld=/opt/gcc-5.3.0/bin/ld --with-as=/opt/gcc-5.3.0/bin/as` assuming gcc-5.3.0 and the build directory, `objdir`, are at the same
  level.
- Do `make` followed by `make install` in the `objdir` build directory.

To verify that the `ld` used by the newly-built `gcc` is the one from the new binutils:

```
/opt/gcc-5.3.0/bin/gcc -print-prog-name=ld
```

The output should be, in this example:

```
/opt/gcc-5.3.0/bin/ld
```

Another test: rename the system `ld`, in my case `/usr/bin/ld`; the newly-built gcc should still work.

Of course, this applies to both `ld` and `as`.

Setting AS and LD environment variables to point to the newly-built binaries from the binutils package did not work: the `-print-prog-name=...` still showed default tools, and removing/renaming the default tools caused gcc to fail.

Thus the best way of accomplishing this is to build binutils first and then use the `--with-ld` and `--with-as` options to `configure`.  If you also want to ensure that the newly-built binutils are used to build GCC, you may want to put them in the PATH before the system-provided tools, or you can even rename the system-provided tools to keep them out of the picture.

Thank you for checking with another mailing list to verify that building GCC and binutils together doesn't work unless they are pulled from the source control, I guess that option is not applicable when using downloaded tarballs.  Overall this was an interesting exercise.

Comment: I've tried this.  But then the built GCC ends up using the system ld, not the one from binutils 2.26.

Comment: I see now.  I've found some instructions that are similar to what you described, but those are 6-7 years old, things may have changed.  I'll play with it on my Ubuntu 14.04 when I find time, looks like an interesting question.

Comment: I've got it to work in the end by building binutils, installing, then configuring gcc with `AS=/path/to/as-mine` and `LD=/path/to/ld-mine`.  I read that you can also use `--with-as=...` and `--with-ld=...` as options to configure, but haven't tried them.

Comment: Looks like a great idea, but you might want to re-build binutils with the more recent gcc.  I've updated my answer, but still need to play with this.

Comment: I tried a build similar to what you described in the original post and ran into a similar error.  It appears to be an inconsistency between scripts and directory names, basically a bug in the build process; will investigate more...

Comment: The response on the binutils mailing list was that building the two directory trees together is only supported when fetching from source control; if you're trying to build released versions of both then it won't (necessarily) work, as shared files / directories may have changed between the two releases.  If you want to update this to mention the `AS=... LD=...` and `--with-as=... --with-ld=...` options, I'll mark it as correct.